# How to access data from FlatList in to parent component to be used in a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

i'm trying to access the `code` and `name` value from within my child component which is a flatlist and access the select data in the parent component:

My flatList is as follows & it house a child component on which it will render items to. But however i get undefind or maybe i've used the wrong approach

```
const CustomerView = ({ code, name, email, balance, buttonPress }: any) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={buttonPress}>
        <Text>Code: {code}</Text>
        <Text>Name: {name}</Text>
        <Text>E-Mail: {email}</Text>
        <Text>Balance: {balance}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And below is my flatList component which will render the above componet when data gets passed through

```
const CustomerFlatList = ({
  customerData,
  onPressSelectCustomer,
}: any) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <FlatList
        data={customerData}
        keyExtractor={(customerData) => customerData.code.toString()}
        //I need to access code and name in the parent component
        renderItem={({ item: { code, name, email, balance } }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <CustomerView
                code={code}
                name={name}
                email={email}
                balance={balance}
                buttonPress={onPressSelectCustomer}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

And my home component which is supposed to get `code, name` passed through in order to trigger an event with there data being passed through

```
const SelectCustomerScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const customers = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.customers);

  const getCustomerDetails = (code, name) => {
      //navigation.navigate("orderScreen");
      console.log(code, name)
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <CustomerFlatList
        customerData={customers}
        doc_type={documentType}
        invoiceScreen={invoiceScreen}
        quotationScreen={quotationScreen}
        onPressSelectCustomer={getCustomerDetails}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks ok to me at first glance. Is your selector returning the correct data? Is the data an array?

Comment: yes it is return the correct data, but whenever I: ```<CustomerView buttonPress={console.log(code)} />``` I get the data but when I do it from the parent component I get undefined or sometimes it returns a random list of strings and objects

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Change the handler to `buttonPress={() => onPressSelectCustomer(code, name)}`. Right now, the only thing that's being passed is the press event from the TouchableOpacity

Comment: Thank you it worked